# TypeError: Variable is Null

Tags: javascript, onload

I keep getting an error with roughly the following code.

```
38. var element_to_precede = document.getElementById("element");
39. var parent_element = element_to_precede.parentNode;
```

It equates roughly to

> line 39: TypeError: element_to_precede is null"

I have been reading around but what I have tried just doesn't work. I have in my main.js,

```
'contentScriptWhen: "ready"'
```

in theory this is supposed to load the script only when everything else has finished loading. The only logical explanation is that this is failing somehow.

I have tried wrapping the code with

```
window.onload = function() {
  //Summon function that calls for element_to_precede here
}
```

Where I ask it to load the elements. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to change anything.

I'm primarily messing with trying to create an extension so I'm using mozilla's tutorials.

Please don't suggest jQuery I'm sure there's a solution in standard JavaScript that I'm missing or not implementing correctly. I'm likely missing something fundamental but for the life of me can't figure out what it is.

Edit.

For example, the code I've tried.

```
window.onload=function(){
  var container = document.createElement("div");
  var element_to_precede = document.getElementById("element")
  var parent_element = element_to_precede.parentNode;
  parent_element.insertBefore(container, element_to_precede);
}
```

Returns

> JavaScript error:  line 39: TypeError: element_to_precede is null

**Edit**
After going through the code again I have found that contrary to what I'm being told the system does...something isn't happening

After asking it the following commands

```
if(document.readyState === "complete") {
  console.log("In theory everything is already loaded");
  console.log("Detected: " + document.getElementById("element") + " element");
}
```

I discovered that it would cycle round four times. Each time it would tell me that everything has already been loaded but that `null element` was detected. Implying that in fact the page is not "complete".

I'm tempted to just put in a wait order for 200 milliseconds or so every time it finds out that it wasn't detected.

So back to the original question. How the heck do I stop this?

Comment: Parentnode. Is it some sort of recursion that ends up returning null when you are at the root?

Comment: if you have error `element_to_precede is null` so `document.getElementByID("element")` return `null`. Are you sure that you have element with this id? also you have type: `getElementByID` should be `getElementById`

Comment: In what environment/platform/library does `contentScriptWhen` exist?

Comment: @Grundy, I am absolutely positive that by the time the page has fully completely loaded that "element" exists. I know this because the code displays as it should. As for that getElemenbyByID please excuse the typo, I will update that shortly.

Comment: @torazaburo Mozilla SDK https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/Loading_Content_Scripts

Comment: @Myut can you provide a bit more your code?

Comment: @Myut That document applies to content scripts (in add-ons). Are you making an add-on? Also, can you show us what the element you are trying to select looks like?

Comment: At least...I'm attempting to make an addon...
The element that i'm attempting to use here is basically just <div id="element" class="someClass"><a class="someClass">text</a></div>. The intention is to create an extra "link" with an additional page. But that's a problem I wish to attempt to tackle on my own first.

Comment: I noted that I had misread "contentScriptWhen" as it automatically defaults to "end" and therefore isn't needed. After taking this out, window.onload failed me and was causing the data not to display at all. Removing the function wrap allowed the data to display bringing me back to the point of beginning. I get no other errors bar that darn null...